# Обработка Get запроса

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток есть get запрос выглядит он примерно так

```
&child=3
&childName=Misha
&childName=Grisha
&childName=Dasha
```

при выводе

```
<?php 
var_dump($_GET[childName]); ?>
```

как вы понимаете получается Dasha, а вот это дело

```
<?phpforeach($_GET[childName] as $chaildName){
    $chaildName.=$chaildName;
}?>
```

ругается вот так Invalid argument supplied for foreach() помогите в чем дело ?

Comment: $_GET[childName] уже не массив, a строка.  как же по нему цикл делать? :)

Comment: К элементам массивов правильнее обращаться так $_GET['childName'], а не так $_GET[childName] ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`childName` передается в запросе как строка. При этом, последующие значения переопределяют предыдущие. Если вам действительно нужен массив, придется изменить запрос на:

```
&child=3
&childName[]=Misha
&childName[]=Grisha
&childName[]=Dasha
```